# Is there away to redirect user back to login in custom authorizer api-gateway auth0 when token is expired?

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway, auth0, serverless, lambda-authorizer

I have been trying to customize custom authorizer to logout user or redirect user to login page when token is expired. I am using auth0, api-gate which I am new to both and I am using aws-node and jwt to verify user token.

here is my authorizer.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
exports.handler = (event) {
  const token = event.authorizationToken;
  try {
    jwt.verify(token,.....) // I am verifing token and I get back expired token and hitting the catch block but, there I don't know how to make the user redirect or respond with 302, I have tried many ways
  } catch(e) { 
      // what to do here?
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help. and if I am taking a wrong approach please tell me guys I am new to this, any recommendations are highly appreciated. Thanks again